# Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'any' can't be used to index type 'Item'

Tags: reactjs, typescript

There are lots of posts answering similar questions, but I cannot get this to work in the context of my code.

I want to index an object based on a string and am getting this error:

> Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'any' can't be used to index type 'Item'.

My function:

```js
export type ListItems = Array<Item>;

export interface Item {
    id: number;
    name: string;
}

export function sortList(list: ListItems, sortkey: string): ListItems {
    return list.sort((a, b) => a[sortkey].localeCompare(b[sortkey]));
}
```

How can I get TypeScript to index type of `Item` using `sortKey`?

Comment: Where is `ListItems` declared?

Comment: @EvanTrimboli, sorry I have updated the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can limit the properties that can be passed in using `keyof`:

```js
export function sortList(list: ListItems, sortKey: keyof Item): ListItems {
    return list.sort((a, b) => a[sortKey].localeCompare(b[sortKey]));
}
```

The problem you will have however, is that it's using `localeCompare`, which assumes the value is a string. Since `sortKey` could refer to `id` which is a number,`localCompare` isn't valid to call. So you have a few options:

- Call `toString` on both values before comparing them.
- Limit the keys to only include string types
- Provide some custom sorter function

For option #2, you can use something like:

```js
type ItemStringsOnly = Pick<Item, { 
    [K in keyof Item]: Item[K] extends string ? K : never 
}[keyof Item]>;

export function sortList(list: ListItems, sortKey: keyof ItemStringsOnly): ListItems {
    return list.sort((a, b) => a[sortKey].localeCompare(b[sortKey]));
}
```